# Nested Attributes for Mongoid has_one relationship

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am trying to create a contact which is a has_one relation to a client. I am doing this with nested attributes. I am properly building the contact within the "new" view/controller. When I go to save the contact it is telling me the contact must be present. So for some reason it is not creating the contact.

**ERROR:**

```
Validation failed - Contact can't be blank.
```

**Params:**

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"ep6es356WY5dja7D7C5Kj8Qc0Yvuh3IN2Z1iGG08J7c=",
  "client"=>{
    "contact_attributes"=>{
      "first_name"=>"Scott",
      "last_name"=>"Baute"
    },
  "commit"=>"Create Client"
}
```

**Models:**

```
class Client
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  attr_accessible :role, :contact_id, :contact_attributes

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :firm, validate: true
  has_one :contact, validate: true, autosave: true

  # Matters is custom relationship
  has_many :client_roles

  # Nested Attr
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact

  validates :contact_id, presence: true

  # Fields
  field :contact_id
  field :test
end

class Contact
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  #Relationships
  belongs_to :client

  field :first_name
  field :last_name

end
```

**Controller:**

```
# GET /clients/new
# GET /clients/new.json
def new
  @client = current_firm.clients.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @client }
  end
end

# POST /clients
# POST /clients.json
def create
  @client = current_firm.clients.new(params[:client])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @client.save!
      format.html { redirect_to client_path(@client.contact.id), notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @client, status: :created, location: @client }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**View:**

```
- @client.build_contact unless @client_contact
= semantic_form_for @client, html: { class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
  .control-group
    = render "contact_fields", f: builder    
  .form-actions
    = f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need delete your reference to contact_id in your Client model. The has_one association do the foreign_key in your contact. Not in your client. So when you create a contact from client, only a client_id is define in your contact no contact_id in your client.

So delete line :

```
validates :contact_id, presence: true

# Fields
field :contact_id
```

in your Client model.